# How to add Jasmine autocomplete to WebStorm 7.0

Tags: autocomplete, jasmine, webstorm

I search around the net but did't find a concrete answer. Please help - How to add Jasmine autocomplete to WebStorm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to download jasmine.js and configure it as a library (Settings/javaScript/Libraries, Add...)

Comment: Eric's answer is correct. add jasmine.js will not work.

Comment: this answer is correct for WebStorm 7. See the date - it's 3 year old. I never recommend things before checking that they work. Indeed, typescript stubs work better. But there was no such option in WebStorm 7.

Answer (score 35):

Here's the step-by-step process for adding library definitions, which are provided courtesy of [borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) at GitHub.

1. In WebStorm, open the Settings dialog (File > Settings).
2. Under the Project Settings category, navigate to JavaScript > Libraries.
3. Click the Download button on the right side. This opens the Download Library dialog.
4. Select "TypeScript community stubs" from the combo box.
5. Find the library you're looking for, select it and click Download and Install.

To restrict usage of a library definition to specific files/folders, use the Manage Scopes dialog. In your case, you might consider it appropriate to only show Jasmine autocomplete in your test spec folder.

NOTE: Even though the dialog is named Download Library, this process is only for downloading the **definition** of the library (method signatures, types, etc). You still need to download the actual library yourself to use it.